# Find 3rd side, given two sides and bearings

Tags: trigonometry

The bearing from A to B is N $42^\circ$ E. The bearing from B to C is S $44^\circ$ E. A small plane traveling $65$ miles per hour, takes $1$ hour to go from A to B and $2$ hours to go from B to C. Find the distance from A to C.

Comment: Showing what you have tried would help us to know what is troubling you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [US Army definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_%28navigation%29#US_Army_definition) of bearing, which this question seems to be using by the format, the layout is as follows:

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

Using the Law of Cosines, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{AC}^2
&=\overline{AB}^2+\overline{BC}^2-2\overline{AB}\,\overline{BC}\cos(\angle ABC)\\
&=65^2+130^2-2\cdot65\cdot130\cos(86^\circ)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $<ABC = 42+44 = 86^\circ$, and $AB = 65$, $BC = 130$. Use law of cosine to get the answer.

Comment: Note that the problem gives the degrees is compass degree headings such that the $<ABC$ is NOT $86^\circ$, but something like $(90 - 42)^\circ + (90 - 44)^\circ = 94^\circ$.



You can see the diagram here: http://www.directlinesoftware.com/r1.gif

Answer (score 0):

City A is furthest west.  City C is furthest east.  City B is furthest north.  So cities A,B,C make a triangle.  Let D denote that point on the base of the triangle that is directly south from B.  So the bearing from A to B is N 42∘ E, but by alternate interior angles, angle A,B,D is also 42∘.  The bearing from B to C is S 44∘ E.  So angle D,B,C is 44∘.  Thus angle A,B,C is 42∘ + 44∘ = 86∘.  So, despite "birdkiller's" comment, I think that 86∘ is correct.  The law of cosines is indeed the correct formula to apply.  Begin with $b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2acCosB$.

Answer (score 0):

Start at $A$, go $42^o$ to B and then head $46^o$ to $C$. So the angle at $B$ is $(90-42)^o+46^o=94^o$,  $c=AB=65$ and $a=BC=130$.  Now use the law of cosines
$b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos B$ to get $b=149.34$